# AWS GlueContext not getting initialize

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm, aws-glue

I am new to AWS and glue services, trying to work with pycharm and I have a python class which reads the data from S3 location, which is working fine. The python class connects to DevEndPoint and odes its work.
I want to create similar practice on my laptop without connecting to Devendpoint(like we do for spark-hadoop application using winutils), bit when i run the applciation on pycharm i am getting below error :

```
C:\Users\****\PycharmProjects\AWSEndpoint\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/AWSEndpoint/src/StackOver.py
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/PycharmProjects/AWSEndpoint/src/StackOver.py", line 9, in <module>
    glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
  File "C:\Python\lib\awsglue\context.py", line 45, in __init__
    self._glue_scala_context = self._get_glue_scala_context(**options)
  File "C:\Python\lib\awsglue\context.py", line 66, in _get_glue_scala_context
    return self._jvm.GlueContext(self._jsc.sc())
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

below is the code that i am using :

```
from py4j.java_gateway import java_import
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, StringType, Row
from src.readConfig import read_config
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

# spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

newconf = sc._conf.set("spark.sql.catalogImplementation", "in-memory")
sc = sc.getOrCreate(newconf)
glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())


def main():
    # glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
    logger = glueContext.get_logger()
    logger.info("Job Started")
     inputDf = glueContext.sparkSession.read.csv(input_dir)
     print(inputDf.take(3))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any suggestion will be helpful, i tried all AWS documentstions.

Comment: The GlueContext is painful :(

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I opened an issue with the awslabs/aws-glue-libs project ~ https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-libs/issues/58